# Computation and Interpretation of Odds Ratio with continuous variables with interaction, in a binary logistic regression model

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio, odds

## Question

A binary logistic regression model has been fitted, with the following output;

```
    Coefficients

    Term                Coef  SE Coef         95% CI          Z-Value  P-Value 
    Constant           -9.80     3.02    (  -17.00,   -4.19)    -3.12    0.001
    A                   0.756    0.510   (  -0.150,   1.552)     1.58    0.103 
    B                   0.0406   0.0201  ( -0.0046,  0.0798)     1.79    0.069
    A*B                -0.00303  0.00298 (-0.00897, 0.00341)    -0.91    0.341 

    Odds Ratios for Continuous Predictors

            Odds    95%
            Ratio    CI
    A          *   (*, *)
    B          *   (*, *)
```

Where $A,B$ are both continuous values $> 0$.

How would one give and interpret the odds ratios for one of  $A$ or $B$ here?

Typically one would state that (for $A$ here) the odds ratio would be
$\exp(0.756 ) = 2.13$, but given there's interaction this is less clear.

As the variables are continuous it also seems more confusing, if  $B$ was been
a binary value then  could interpret the model as

$$
\text{log} \left(
\frac{p}{1 - p} 
\right)
=
 \beta_0 + \beta_1 A + \beta_2 B + \beta_3 A \times B
$$

If $B = 0$ then

$$
\text{log} \left(
\frac{p}{1 - p} 
\right)
 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 A 
$$

If $B = 1$ then

$$
\text{log} \left(
\frac{p}{1 - p} 
\right)
= \beta_0 + ( \beta_1 + \beta_3 )A 
$$

And state that *if $B$ is present then an increase of $A$ by one unit increases the odds by a factor of*
$\exp(\beta_1 + \beta_3) = \exp(0.756 - 0.00303)$. And
*if $B$ is not present then an increase of $A$ by one unit increases the odds by a factor of*
$\exp(\beta_1)$

How to go about computation and interpretation of odds ratios in the case of interaction with continuous variables?

---

### Why I don't think this is a duplicate

[From exp (coefficients) to Odds Ratio and their interpretation in Logistic Regression with factors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136193/from-exp-coefficients-to-odds-ratio-and-their-interpretation-in-logistic-regre)
, talks about using categorical variables and has only one factor with three levels (red, orange, blue)

[Interaction Test with Odds
Ratio](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61186/interaction-test-with-odds-ratio)
didn't talk about a similar scenario to my question.

[Log odds ratio and unadjusted log odds ratio when we have a continuous
variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54511/log-odds-ratio-and-unadjusted-log-odds-ratio-when-we-have-a-continuous-variable)
sounds similar, but is really about putting the continuous variables into
buckets rather than the interpretation of them in the context that I have given.

[Comparing odds ratios of continuous and discrete
variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23267/comparing-odds-ratios-of-continuous-and-discrete-variables)
is discussing their design.

[Interpretation of continuous by continuous interaction in binary regression
model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206717/interpretation-of-continuous-by-continuous-interaction-in-binary-regression-mode)
doesn't have an answer, in the comments there are links to 
[this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/how-can-one-plot-continuous-by-continuous-interactions-in-ggplot2)
post
[and this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141362/how-can-i-get-slope-and-standard-error-at-several-levels-of-a-continuous-by-cont)
post, neither of which appear to answer the question, or mine.

[Odds ratios for continuous independent variables
[duplicate]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142809/odds-ratios-for-continuous-independent-variables)
has been flagged as a duplicate, although the post that has been linked ( 
   this post
) doesn't appear to answer the problem as it's talking about categorical
variables ( I have mentioned this post already, red, orange, blue).

In the last thread linked above whuber has stated the information is already
there, I feel that it would be a good idea to have an explicit answer in
relation to the example that I have provided as the topic seems to be confusing
to other learners as well as myself.

---

Answer (score 4):

If your predictors A and B are both continuous and they interact in their effect, then your binary logistic regression model is:

$$
\text{log(p/(1-p))} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 A + \beta_2 B + \beta_3 A \times B
$$

where p is the conditional probability of "success" given A and B. (In other words, p is the conditional probability that your binary outcome variable takes the value 1 rather than 0 given A and B, where 1 = "success" and 0 = "failure".) Furthermore, p/(1-p) denotes the conditional odds of "success" given A and B.

Assume you are now interested in the effect of A on the (conditional) log odds of "success"; because A and B interact, the effect of A depends on the (effect of) B and you can determine it by re-expressing the above model like this:

$$
\text{log(p/(1-p))} = \beta_0 + (\beta_1 + \beta_3  B)  A + \beta_2  B
$$

Thus, via exponentiation of the coefficient of A in the above model re-expression, you can determine that a 1-unit increase in the value of A changes the odds of "success" by a multiplicative factor of $exp(\beta_1 + \beta_3  B)$.

You can give B certain values to see more explicitly how this multiplicative factor describing the effect of A on the odds of success gets affected by the values of B - for example, consider values for B such as mean(B) - sd(B), mean(B), mean(B) + sd(B) if the distribution of B is roughly symmetric and unimodal.

A similar argument as described above can be used to quantify the effect of B on the odds of success as a function of (the effect of) A.

Comment: logit is function, such as log. so logit itself has no meaning.

Comment: @a_statistician in certain fields, it is common to use logits as shorthand for log odds. So it is not so strange to see something like "expected logits"

Comment: @a_statistician: It is clear from the question that baxx uses logit as a shortcut for the log odds of success. But I modified my answer to appease your concern.  You should have added your comment underneath the question itself - as a statistician, I know what logit stands for but I wanted to use a language that baxx can easily understand. If you find my answer unsatisfactory, nobody is stopping you from adding your own answer.  Personally, I don't like taking away from other people's answers - I'd rather provide a different answer. Otherwise, I may come across as the "Answer Police".

Comment: Maybe this is an instance of mansplaining? It makes me sad if that is the case. Presumably, we are all here to help other people.

Comment: I understood what you meant @IsabellaGhement and what you're saying is consistent with what I understood it to mean. I can't comment about standards or such though, I'll edit my post to reflect this notation

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, it is probably easier to interpret this graphically. I will make certain assumptions to demonstrate the thought process for interpreting interactions like this:

- $A$ is my predictor of interest, so I will interpret the odds ratio of $A$ at varying levels of $B$, and
- $B$ has a range $[0, 100]$ with mean of 50 and most values falling in $[25, 75]$ such that this is the range of interest.

In the scenario I have set up, the actual log odds of $A$, 0.756, is probably not of interest since it is the log odds of $A$ when $B=0$ and $B=0$ applies to so few people in the data that we do not care for it.

I will calculate the log-odds of $A$ when $B=\{25,50,75\}$. This results in:

\begin{align}
\beta_1 + \beta_3 \times \{25, 50, 75\}&{}=\\
0.756 -0.00303 \times \{25, 50, 75\}&{}=\\
\{0.756 -0.07575, 0.756 -0.15150, 0.756 -0.22725\}&{}=\\
\{0.68025, 0.60450, 0.52875\}
\end{align}

The odds ratio of $A$ will then be $1.97\ (e^{0.68025})$, $1.83\ (e^{0.60450})$, $1.70\ (e^{0.52875})$ when $B=\{25, 50, 75\}$ respectively.

So you find that the odds ratio of $A$ drops as the value of $B$ increases. We can also graph the set-up at varying values of B:

[image]

To create the graph, I used all integer values of $B$ in $[25, 75]$.

Comment: From this then, it's not possible to only give the odds ratio of $A$ in this context? By which I mean, reporting $\exp(0.756)$ is incorrect because of the interaction ( I can't report this as being *adjusted for B and AxB* ). And in the case of $\exp(\beta_1 + \beta_3 \times B )$ it's not an odds ratio only for $A$, because it contains B. Does that make sense? Thanks

Comment: @baxx something like that. It depends on the value of B. You effectively tie them together by setting up an interaction.

Comment: @baxx there's nothing stopping you from interpreting the exponentiated coefficient but it's only true when B = 0. And as in my example, that can be grossly irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

It is not easy to put this into words or to visualise it but let us attempt the task.

The coefficient is, as the output suggests, for the value of $A*B$ so let us suppose that has the value 4. We know that $e^{4 * -0.00303} = 0.988$. This means that for an increase in $A*B$ of 4 the predicted odds are multiplied by 0.988. Now it does not matter how you got to increase $A*B$ by 4, it could be by increasing $A$ by 1 and $B$ by 4, $A$ by 4 and $B$ by 1, or increasing each by 2, or any of the uncountably many ways of making their product 4. You have to include the coefficients for $A$ and $B$ as well to get the full picture, of course.

[image: Perspective plot of the logit as a function of a and b]

The perspective plot shows the value of the equation specified in terms of the logit for values of $A$ and $B$ from 0 to 100 (denoted f, a and b in the plot).
Note the very slight inclination in both directions corresponding to the small interaction effect. Despite the apparent curvature this is just an optical effect the surface is flat.

I would speculate that the reason we see so few linear by linear interactions in my field is because they are so hard to understand and explain to the readers.

Comment: so given this how would one go about considering the odds ratio for $A$? Presumably to state that the odds ratio for $A$ is $\exp(0.756)$ would be incorrect, as we have the interaction present as well. However, I can't consider cases because $B$ doesn't have levels, it's a continuous variable. So I'm still unsure how to go about finding the odds ratio for $A$ in this case. Thanks

Comment: You cannot interpret the main effects in any simple way in the presence of an interaction. In a sense that is what interaction means although it is not usually expressed like that.

Comment: I'm curious what your thoughts are about the other responses then. Would you consider it valid to interpret the odds ratio for $A$ by choosing a few particular values of $B$ and finding the exponential $\exp(0.756 -0.00303 \times B )$ ?

Comment: Yes, of course it is valid. Anything which helps interpretation is valid.